# Does watering plants with purified water yield better results?

Tags: biology, water, plants

I watched a commercial for the [Aquaguard Enhance RO+UV water purifier](https://www.eurekaforbes.com/water-purifiers/aquaguard-enhance-ro-uv)  recently.

In that commercial, a science teacher assigns an experiment to students. The students bringing a plant to school, and observe its growth over several days.
One student's plant looks more fresh and healthy than the remaining plants. When teacher asks the reason, the pupil says he used water from an Aquaguard purifier.

The reason they gave is that the purifier discriminates essential minerals and doesn't remove them from water. I did not find this reason plausible.

Does proof that watering plants with purified water yields better results when compared to watering with tap water?

Comment: Please find the commercial and the name of the company/product and add that to your a question.

Comment: You're asking multiple questions here.  Do you want to know if pure distilled water is better than (naturally) mineralized water, or do you want to know if a filter could filter contaminants while leaving essential minerals?

Comment: @JMac My main question is asked in the title and in the conclusion in the question. Does watering plants with purified water yields better results when compared to watering with normal water?

Comment: @NogShine Does "purified" mean clean to drink, or completely distilled though?  Your premise seems to be a filter that "discriminates essential minerals"; which implies it's not distilling; but instead removing contaminants.  You claim purified water is devoid of essential minerals; but my understanding was that the filter in question didn't remove them.  So essentially the notable claim you cite is different than the question asked.

Comment: I think the claim Aquaguard is making is that in contrast to other filters which remove essential minerals from water, the Aquaguard purifier is smart enough to keep the essential minerals intact.  If that's what they're saying, it might be better to ask about the Aquaguard purifier and not water filters in general.

Comment: Try drinking distilled water, see what happens. Filters like the one you describe surely don't output that as you claim. And what is "normal water"? Tap water in India (where Aquaguard is sold) [tends to be pretty bad](https://www.outlookindia.com/website/story/world-water-day-is-indias-drinking-water-standards-diluted/298298). Sure the ad may be misleading, but your post is even more so.

Comment: Until we find the commercial, it isn't clear which model of Aquaguard purifier is being used, but if it is the [Aquaguard Classic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rffYiY7nCUc) it is NOT distilled water. It is a three-step process: filtered, another step (ion-exchange, I think) and then exposed to UV to kill bugs. I've edited out mention of distilled water as a red herring.

Comment: @Oddthinking This exact commercial about science experiment is not available on the internet but commercial about the product is available. Is it okay to add it? The product is not Aquaguard classic. It is  Dr.Aquaguard RO +UV. It doesn't do the distillation either. It removes contaminants, restores minerals. My main question is not whether a purifier can restore minerals. The question is does it yield better results if watered with purified water.

Comment: @LangLang: Forget "pure water" and "distilled water"; they aren't the claim. We are talking about *purified* water, - i.e. water from one of these purifiers.  While Bhopal waste water is a bit extreme, I think you point about "depends on the tap water quality" is fair and should probably appear in the answer.

Comment: Something that hasn't been commented on but needs to be considered: What plant species was that? For example, there are plants like [Drosera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drosera) that should be watered with deionized or distilled water, other plants benefit from lime added via tap water.

Comment: We try not to examine claims based on fiction. Commercials are fiction.